# Check if IPv4 / IPV6 is within range from mysql Table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables table with IPV4,IPv6  with starting range and ending range like below

Below is ipv4 table where I converted all ipv4 using `INET_ATON`

```
    START      |   END
--------------------------------
    3423540224 |   3423541247
    1161801728 |   1161805823
```

Below is ipv6 table where I converted all ipv6 using `INET6_ATON`

```
    START                   |   END
------------------------------------------------------------
    0x262000001c00000000000 |   0x262000001cfffffffffffffff
    0x262003210200000000000 |   0x262033211cfffffffffffffff
```

Now I have the one of original IP address 123.123.21.21 , I wanted to test if this Ip exists within any of the range in table.I tried below query but it returns empty.

```
SELECT * FROM `ipv4` WHERE (INET_ATON("123.123.21.21") BETWEEN INET_NTOA(`START`) AND INET_NTOA(`END`))
```

Also I want to check for IPv6 , Which I tried

```
 SELECT * FROM `ipv4` WHERE (INET6_ATON("2213:1880:test:0:0:0:0:0") BETWEEN INET6_NTOA(`START`) AND INET6_NTOA(`END`))
```

But above queries always return empty.Can some one tell best way to do it ?
P.s: I have only 256 total rows of CIDR range

Comment: You need to pick a type to compare; you're comparing ATON return value to NTOA return values.

Comment: ...even if you weren't `INET_ATON("123.123.21.21")` is not between either of those first sets of `START` `END` pairs.

Comment: did you find any solution because I have same task like you and giving same result?